# How to load dependent certificates in a Node JS App

Tags: node.js, ssl

I have 3 certificates which are setup as follows: CA1.crt, CA2.crt and CA_Root.crt, CA_Root.crt is the root certificate.
However, the other certificates are needed to be loaded for the for the setup to work. The order of the certificates in the chain are CA1.crt, C2.crt and finally CA_Root.crt. Looking at the documentation for NodeJS, I cannot find a way to load more than 1 certificate. Here is the example from the documentation:

```js
                          ssl: {
                              rejectUnauthorized: false,
                              ca: [readFileSync('./cert_1.crt', 'utf-8')]
                          }
```

From looking at the example it seems possible to load more than 1 certificate since it is an array, is that the way to do it?